# Coordinates - Latitude/longitude

Tags: r, compiler-errors, shapefile, choropleth

[image]
Kindly provide me with some assistance, I'm unable to plot my map as I am unable to identify the longitude and latitude coordinates in my shapefile. Also when I run my code I keep getting this error message. I fairly new to using R so everything is still overwhelming. Attached is my merged data please help me identify these coordinates.

```
ggplot() +
   geom_polygon(data = merged_data, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = Unemployment_Rate)) +
   labs(title = "Unemployment Rates in the U.S. (2015)",
        fill = "Unemployment Rate") +
   scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") +
   theme_void()
```

> Error in `geom_polygon()`: ! Problem while computing aesthetics. ℹ
> Error occurred in the 1st layer. Caused by error: ! object 'long' not
> found

Comment: Try: `ggplot() + geom_sf(data= merged_data, aes(fill=Unemployment Rate))`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I tried that and got this error message: Error in `geom_polygon()`:
! Problem while setting up geom.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `compute_geom_1()`:
! `geom_polygon()` requires the following missing
  aesthetics: x and y

Comment: Welome to Stackoverflow; Please provide a minimal reproducible example(s) that others can run using copy and paste. Use dput() for data. Don't embed pictures for data or code. [Helpful guidance for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Use `geom_sf()` not `geom_polygon()`!

Comment: Also, my map seems to be sized too small. Is there a code I can use to increase the size?

Comment: Time to close. No data. Read [MCVE]